# ruby hash to java hashmap using rjb

Tags: java, ruby, hash, hashmap

How can I pass a ruby hash to a java constructor which will store it in a HashMap?

I tried the following code, but it throws a "can't convert to java type" exception:

```
Rjb::import("java.util.HashMap").new({:name => 'test'})
```

I need to use mri + rjb, not jruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up just adding the items one by one:

```
hashmap = Rjb::import("java.util.HashMap").new
item.each_pair{ |k, v| hashmap.put(k, v) }
```